# Is there a standard library function that reverses STL stacks?

Tags: c++, stl

By reverse I mean swap the order of the elements so a stack containing ABCD ends up with DCBA. I am currently using vectors instead of stacks just because of the reverse operation.

Comment: would std::sort be sufficient?

Comment: I dont want to sort, I want to reverse. ACBD -> DBCA

Comment: this made me curious. my search makes me think nothing is in the standard library, but here's a recursive function to reverse in place: http://dev-faqs.blogspot.com/2012/02/reverse-given-stack-in-place.html.

Comment: Sounds sort of like a hybrid stack-deque container.

Comment: well yea, sort wont work here

Comment: I'd say just use `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::stack<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) operates by wrapping an underlying container, typically `std::deque<T>`.

```
// According to cppreference.com
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

There's no reason to use a `std::stack` instead of a `std::vector` or a `std::deque` unless all you care about is the top element. The structure doesn't even expose iterators, and that's part of the design.

Sure you can write a fancy function to reverse it (store the top, pop, push to a new stack, repeat), but why do more work than you have to?

Answer (score 3):

A stack is a container that provides a nice simple push/pop/top interface. What you are asking for is actually not stack functionality so that implies that a stack is the wrong container for your needs.

Most likely either a `vector` or `deque` would be a good choice (as you have already mentioned in your question) as they provide constant time push/pop back capabilities, as well as a linear time reversal (`std::reverse`).

Comment: Actually, in C++ stack is _not_ a container. Both terms have specific meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The STL stack is not a container, it's a container adapter ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/ ).  The underlying container type is passed as an argument to the template, with the default being deque.  The short answer to your question is 'no' -- the stack interface doesn't provide that capability.

The two options I see are:

1. Use the stack interface (pure stack solution) as described above (link repeated here for convenience):
   http://dev-faqs.blogspot.com/2012/02/reverse-given-stack-in-place.html
2. Use a more flexible structure as you have done (e.g. vector or deque).  In this case it probably makes the most sense to use a deque and push/pop from either end, depending on whether you're using the sequence in "forward" or "reverse" mode.  That's most efficient.